# How I get the Unicode values from a VARCHAR in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, unicode

I want to return the unicode values from the values of a column in PostgreSQL.

Is this possible? How I do?

**Example:**

```
"Renato" : U+0022 U+0052 U+0065 U+006E U+0061 U+0074 U+006F U+0022
```

I want to do this because I want to discover the Unicode from some symbols and punctuations to add to a conversion regex to replace these values to others.

Comment: Please define "unicode values". Can you add examples?

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter I added an example to the question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Get one Unicode code point:

```
SELECT ascii('ã')
```

Result:

```
227
```

More [in the manual here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-OTHER). A quote:

> For UTF8 returns the Unicode code point of the character.

Get Unicode code points for a string:

```
SELECT array_agg(t)
FROM (
       SELECT ascii(regexp_split_to_table('Conceição', '')) AS t
     ) x
```

Use [`string_agg`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-aggregate.html) instead if you want a text string as result. For it you have to cast the values to text.

Comment: Yes, I think is this, but this only works for the first char. It's possible work with the entire word?

Comment: @RenatoDinhaniConceição: Please see my amended answer.

Comment: Great. Thank you so much for your help. This will help me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You can list a whole range at once without the need to hand feed characters to the query:

```
select i, chr(i)
from
    generate_series(160, 255) s(i)
order by i
```